In Scala, how difficult is to resolve cyclic type bound declaration?
Here is a short example:
    trait A {
      type Min
      type Max >: Min
    }

    trait B {
      type Max
      type Min <: Max
    }

    trait C extends A with B {}
/*
error: cyclic reference involving type Min
*/

    trait D {

      type Min <: Max
      type Max >: Min
    }
/*
error: illegal cyclic type reference: upper bound D.this.Max of type Min refers back to the type itself
*/

These errors are only thrown because Scala compiler can only infer type bounds based on the graph they refer to others. But since Scala type bounds are from both sides (>: and <:), it is trivial to infer a non-cyclic/monotonic sutyping graph from cyclic references.
What can be done to make the compiler acknowledge the above type definitions?
